# How to get sorted data from one service to another over http

Tags: microservices, api-design

I have service oriented architecture with couple services.

- Product  - store list of products

  `{
     id: number,
     price: number
  }`
- Categories   - store category information + the list of product ids

  `{
     id: number,
     parentCategory: number,
     productIds: number[]
   }`

Lets assume that I have such category instance

```
{
   id: 1,
   parentCategory: null,
   productIds: [1, 3, 4, 5, ....]
}
```

I need to get 10 products from the category above sorted by product price.

Category service processes that request and because it doesn't know anything about the price it has to make the request to Product service like that:

```
/api/products?
   ids=<list of all product ids>
   limit=10
   sortBy=price
```

which won't work well when the category has a lot of products.

What is the recipe in such case? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to get these ids back sorted? Probably you should not receive them back? But pass them forward through Products service where they could be sorted and passed back in another service call and not as response in the right order? You have to pass these ids one way or another, otherwise you would need to have them already sorted in Categories service,

Comment: @cassandrad No, I don't expect to receive sorted ids.
Essentially, сategory asks to sort a predefined list of product ids (ids which belong to certain category) and return only 10 product items back. And I'm worried when the category, for example, will have 1000 product ids it must send all of them over HTTP request.

Comment: Can you add an example with data in both services to your question, please?

Comment: I agree with victor — POST request could solve potential issue. If you are concerned about performance, for example, in case of thousands of ids, you should consider merging this services together. Or duplicate prices data in Categories service. Data duplication and merging several services into one for performance reasons are normal situations in microservices architecture. But if your Products service only stores information and doesn't have any business logic, then I definitely would consider merging.

Comment: Also, consider having all ids already sorted in Categories service. For me it would be the best solution in this case if Products service will not do anything business useful and only sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I decide to merge them together, it seems most reasonable decision in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with victor — POST request could solve potential issue. If you are concerned about performance, for example, in case of thousands of ids, you should consider merging these services together. Or duplicate prices data in Categories service.

Data duplication and merging several services into one for performance reasons are normal situations in microservices architecture. But if your Products service only stores information and doesn't have any business logic, then I definitely would consider merging.

Also, consider having all ids already sorted in Categories service. For me it would be the best solution in this case if Products service will not do anything business useful and only sorting

Answer (score 1):

You should make that endpoint only receive Http Post and then you should put all of the product ids in the body of your request. Something like this:

{
  "ids" : [], (an array with all your ids in it)
  "limit": 10,
  "sortBy": "price"
}

not sure why you have the field "limit", I would think that what controls the limit is how many ids you pass in.

Comment: in my case,  category always has to send all product ids ( it doesnt know how to sort them ) and ask product service sort and return only 10 products back

Comment: ok that is fine. Sending the request in the body of an Http Post should still solve your problem of running out of room in the url.